# which families of PDFs are closed under translation and multiplication?

Tags: probability-distributions

The product of two PDFs is not usually a PDF; but it is a (possibly zero) scalar multiple of another PDF.

I will call a set $S$ of PDFs over $\mathbb{R}$ *closed under translation and multiplication* if

1. $f(x)\in F \Rightarrow f(x-a) \in F$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$;
2. $f, g\in F \Rightarrow fg = \alpha h$ for some $h\in F$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

The set of all Gaussians is one notable nontrivial example of such an $S$. Are there any other notable examples? How rich is the space of such sets $S$?

Comment: Not sure I get your question. Isn't the set of all pdfs with compact support an example?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Sure; my question is, how rich is the set of examples? Other than the obvious examples (the empty set; the set of all PDFs) and the Gaussians, is it very easy to construct a large number of such $S$? Or are there only a few (or a few families) of $S$ with this property?